# How to use Ref in a component that is forwarding its ref in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-component

I have a react native custom input component and I'm successfully forwarding its ref to a parent component.
Now, I also want to refer to the input in the child itself, How do I do this??

```js
//my imports here

//my text field component
export const MyTextField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

   const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');

   const clearInput = () => {
      setValue("");
      //I want to get the input by ref here and apply "clear()" method on it
   }


   return (
      <View>
         <TextInput
            /*
             How can i also use this ref to refer to this textinput in The "clearInput" function above
             */
            ref={ref}
            value={inputValue}
            onChangeText={(value) => setValue(value)}
            {...props}
         />
         <IconButton
            icon="close-circle"
            onPress={clearInput}
         />
      </View>
   );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article by `Travis Waith-Mair` shows what you want to do with details: https://non-traditional.dev/how-to-use-the-forwarded-ref-in-react-1fb108f4e6af

Also there's an npm package of it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bedrock-layout/use-forwarded-ref

---

Here is a snack with examples: https://snack.expo.io/@truetiem/use-forwardedref

If you want to implement it into your code:

```js
// Copy-Pasted the "useForwardedRef" from the linked article by "Travis Waith-Mair"
const useForwardedRef = (ref) =>{
   const innerRef = useRef(null);

   useEffect(() => {
     if (!ref) return;
     if (typeof ref === 'function') {
       ref(innerRef.current);
     } else {
       ref.current = innerRef.current;
     }
   });
 
   return innerRef;
}

export const MyTextField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   // passing the ref to useForwardedRef hook
   const forwardedRef = useForwardedRef(ref);
   const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');

   const clearInput = () => {
      setValue("");
      
      // You can access the ref safely with forwardedRef
      forwardedRef.current?.clean();
   }


   return (
      <View>
         <TextInput
            // Passing the forwardedRef here
            ref={forwardedRef}
            value={inputValue}
            onChangeText={(value) => setValue(value)}
            {...props}
         />
         <IconButton
            icon="close-circle"
            onPress={clearInput}
         />
      </View>
   );
});
```

Comment: This Worked for me. My question was tricky to phrase and make comprehensible, but I'm glad you captured it accurately

Answer (score 0):

To access a ref while also forwarding it:

- Attach a ref created inside the component to the other component
- Call the [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook on the outer ref (which is being forwarded to) and pass a function that returns the `current` property of the inner ref, which is the value that will be set to the `current` property of the outer ref

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState } from 'react';
const MyTextField = forwardRef((props, outerRef) => {
    const innerRef = useRef(null);
    useImperativeHandle(outerRef, () => innerRef.current, []);
    // remember to list any dependencies of the function that returns the ref value, similar to useEffect
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    return <TextInput ref={innerRef} value={inputValue} onChangeText={setInputValue} {...props} />;
});
```